# Replacing static variables in a test

Tags: java, junit, static

I have a helper class with some static final strings as follows

```
public static final String abc = "abc"
```

In my test though, I want to use the value

```
public static final String abc = "xyz"
```

So I added the following

```
private static final HelperClass mock = mock(HelperClass.class);


@Before
when(mock.abc).thenReturn("xyz")
```

The actual code to test

```
public void codeToTest() {
  // use Helperclass.abc
  // other logic
```

But this declaration is not allowed since it needs to be a method invocation. `(MissingMethodInvocation)` How do I use the static variables in the test?

Comment: You should Mock HelperClass class first.

Comment: I did, but it still expects a method istead of the field, I've updated the question

Answer (score 1):

Static values can make some tests a bit more difficult. You won't be able to use mocking to get this value. But I have to ask why you would want to mock this. It isn't testing anything in the helper class to access this variable and you are wanting a constant, why not just define and use the constant in your test?

Comment: The code that I am trying to test is using the this static filed in its logic. I want it to use another variable but exercise the same code path, I've updated the question

Comment: If that code path that is being tested can be given the mock object and if the variable in the mock object is accessed through a getter, then you could do that. As stated though, you won't be able to do what you are wanting.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer (plus you can mock static fields in a variety of ways).  In general I'd agree it's not a great pattern in Java, though.

Answer (score 0):

Create Another Mocked class as below.

```
private static class MockedHelperClass  extends MockUp<HelperClass>
    {
        public static final String abc = "xyz"

        @Mock
        String getABC()
        {
            return abc;
        }
    }
```

Then use this mocked class as below in Test Method

```
MockedHelperClass helperClass = new MockedHelperClass();
helperClass.abc = "xyz";
helperClass.getABC();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should re-think your design, changing static variables in tests isn't a good practice. However, if you really want to to that, you can use reflection.

```
static void setStatic(Field field, Object value) throws Exception {
  field.setAccessible(true);
  Field modifiers = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
  modifiers.setAccessible(true);
  modifiers.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
  field.set(null, value);
}
```

Invocation example:

```
setStatic(MyClass.class.getField("abc"), "xyz");
```